# How this cipher algorithm works?

Tags: algorithm, bash, shell, encryption

I have been asked to implement following cipher algorithm. Encryption is a bit vague but al least it makes a bit sense but I have no idea how decryption works!
As it says, For decryption the reverse substitution should occur. As you can see in this example 'cabbage', How to know that `b` has repeated twice or `a` has occurred before! Maybe there is some hint that I can not see it or I am making mistake somewhere. 
I have taken image from requirement so I can show you the table as well. Appreciate any explanation or algorithm.

[image]

Comment: You simply need to map one character to the other.  AFAICT, whether `b` is repeated or not, or whether it is preceded by `a` should not matter at all.

Comment: I wonder after mapping these letters. How can I decrypt it to get the original word?

Comment: You might want to look at `tr`.  See `man tr`.

Comment: Could you provide an example for keyword, inputfile and outputfile?

Comment: looks like a homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tasked with a simple substitution cipher. To encrypt a text look up every character in the first line and replace with the character in the second line, so a->c, b->a, c->b, etc. To decrypt a text look up every character in the second line and replace it with the character in the first line, so a->b, b->c, c->a, etc. As devnull has pointed out the command to look for is `tr`. The example in your homework (?) can be achieved by

```
tr abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz cabgedfhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz # encryption
tr cabgedfhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz # decryption
```

To construct the table you need to compute the second line (the first one is always a-z). As far as I would interpret the task you start keyword and delete every occurrence of a character but the first, so `abcadc` becomes `abcd` and `rlxxdllllq` becomes `rlxdq`. These characters build the beginning of the second line of your table. You now fill it up with the remaining characters of the alphabet in alphabetic order. So you can get the second word for `tr` by concatenating the singularized keyword with the result of the singularized keyword characters removed from `abcd`…`xyz`. As `tr` has also a delete functionality this should be simple.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like homework so I just add some hints how it works no actual full code ...

1.substitution

- first convert keyword to be from distinct letters only
- remove all letters that was used before (2 nested loops will do)

  ```
  cabbage -> cabge  // b,a removed
  ```
- now make the alphabet substitution table

  ```
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // plain text alphabet(input unencrypted alphabet)
  -------------------------
  cabge                        // keyword
  ---d-f-hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // unused letters
        dfhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // unused letters merged together
  -------------------------
  cabgedfhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // output text alphabet (output encrypted alphabet)
  ```

2.encryption

- just read text and convert any letter from unencrypted alphabet to encrypted
- something like this:

  ```
  char enc[]="cabgedfhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  char in,out;
  // loop for input text reading to in
  out=enc[int(in-'a')];
  // and writing back out
  ```

3.decryption

- create decryption alphabet table

  ```
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // plain text alphabet
  cabgedfhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // enc table
  // now find the letter for decryption in enc and write the plain text value at the same position
  // a->b, b->c, c->a ... z->z also 2 nested loops will do it
  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // plain text alphabet
  bcafegdhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz // dec table
  ```
- now decrypt in the same way as encrypt just use dec table instead of enc

  ```
  char dec[]="bcafegdhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  char in,out;
  // loop for input text reading to in
  out=dec[int(in-'a')];
  // and writing back out
  ```

[Notes]

- do not forget to add if's to handle letters other then 'a' - 'z'

Comment: I think the other answer for encrypt and decrypt is heaps easier and I tested that I don't need two table for encrypt and decrypt one table is good enough. Anyway thanks for your time substitution really helped.

Comment: if you use one table only then you have slower decryption or encryption (need one more search loop per each character), but you spare memory instead. Both approaches are valid so choose what is better for your task ...